# Pushing without committing

Tags: git

I have a git repo and I just pushed it to a server. Then I setup a post-receive hook on the server. I want to check it works. I have to commit again just to see if it works? I would really like to just force a push while I'm trying to get this set up rather than keep making commits that have no real value. Its not working, and I just don't get it.

```
$ git push --force origin master
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: Specifically for GitHub pages on fork: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587321/github-pages-in-forked-repo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to push an older commit to achieve this. For example, you could push the commit right before the current HEAD using this comment:

```
git push --force origin HEAD^:master
```

After this you can push the HEAD commit again:

```
git push origin master
```

However, instead of pushing all the time consider calling the hook manually. That's usually easier - but don't forget to test with an actual push when you think everything works just to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

There's a little dirty trick you can use:

```
git stash save && git push --force origin "stash@{0}:master" && git stash pop
```

This does 3 things:

1. Stash current uncommitted changes.
   Stashing creates a new commit, but on a separate ref. It will not dirty your history. Additionally, it clears the working directory from the changes. See step 3.
2. Push the stashed code
3. Pop the stash - clearing the stash and placing all the files back in your working directory.

This will effectively push all files to the remote without creating a local commit.

Comment: Not a bad solution, but awkward in scripts. If something fails in between the stash and the pop, the user's working directory will be left in an unexpected state. Would love to know if there's a solution that doesn't involve modifying the working directory.